# Writing a script that gets command and executes it

Tags: bash

I want to write a script that gets in its argument a command and executes it while it's running. for example if the script called ex_script, writing

```
ex_script "cat file1.txt | wc -l"
```

and the ex_script is:

```
var=`"${1}"`
echo $var
```

will assign the number of lines in `file1.txt` in `var` and then print it.

But it gives me

```
./ex_script: line 3: cat file1.txt | wc -l: command not found
```

How do I write this correctly?

Comment: This cannot be done in the general case. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: `ex_script` is just reimplementing `sh -c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval`

```
var=$(eval "$1")
echo "$var"
```

Comment: Sure, but why start another shell when you can use the current one? Also, that won't work if it needs to access variables defined in the current shell, unless you export them.

Comment: I was under the impression the OP just wants to write a script that takes an arbitrary command line as input, and output the result of running it. Also, `$(...)` forks a new shell anyway (doesn't it?).

Comment: It runs a subshell of the current shell, it doesn't start a new shell.

Comment: I was under the impression that it wasn't *required* to start a new process, but that most shells did. (I'm not sure how to confirm or deny that assertion without using `strace`, which I'm too lazy to do.)

Comment: @chepner That's why I said "subshell" rather than "subprocess", it depends on the shell and the particular circumstances. Some subprocess actions can be emulated in the same process, others are harder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94247/discussion-between-chepner-and-barmar).